# 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Получаю ошибку
ERROR - Get current temperature error: 'int' object is not subscriptable
При попытке выполнить куска кода

```
@admin_commands
def get_cuurent_temperature(update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    try:
#        conn = sqlite3.connect(SQLITE_DB_FILENAME)
#        cursor = conn.cursor()
#        row = cursor.execute('select temperature from celsread where id = 1').fetchone()
#        conn.close()
        ss = str(subprocess.run(['cat', '/sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/28-000e9843003d/w1_slave'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True))
        t = float(search(r'(?<=t=)\d+\.?\d*', ss).group())
        t = t/1000
        row = round(t)
        text = "Температура в системе {0}".format(row[0])
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id, text, reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(INFO_MENU, resize_keyboard=True))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Get current temperature error: %s', str(e))
        text = "Не удалось получить температуру из-за проблем с БД, Попробуйте еще раз."
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id, text, reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(INFO_MENU, resize_keyboard=True))
```

Это телеграм бот, в котором я попытался внести изменения. Понимаю, что проблема в text = "Температура в системе {0}".format(row[0]), но я не разработчик и причину понять не могу. Прошу помощи.

Comment: `row` — это число. Что вы ожидали получить из числа, написав `row[0]`?

Comment: Я, вероятно, не понимаю о чм речь, но там на выходе и получается число. Вас не затруднит чуть подробнее описать мою ошибку?

Comment: О каком выходе речь? `row` — это число, `text` — это строка, а что вы имели в виду написав `row[0]` — это непонятно

Comment: Выход:/bin/cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/28-000e9843003d/w1_slave
57 01 64 05 7f 00 00 ff 3a : crc=3a YES
57 01 64 05 7f 00 00 ff 3a t=21437

Обрабатываю я то, что после t=
Повторюсь, я не владею пайтоном совершенно, но если правильно понимаю, то row[0] - формат вывода значения.

Comment: У вас написано cuurent вместо current. Может потому ошибка?

Comment: кончайте троллить )) @Zerg, измените text = "Температура в системе {0}".format(row[0]) на text = "Температура в системе {0}".format(row)

Comment: @Jack_oS а чё сразу троллить-то, человек просто не понимает что он тут вообще написал

Comment: @Jack_oS, Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: @DGDays, благодарю, поправил.

Comment: @andreymal, простите нас - неграмотных - за то, что смеем обращаться к Вам - всезнающему и всемогущему божеству. Но так уж случилось, что не все люди работают разработчиками, есть еще медики, юристы, преподаватели, и многие другие, не одарённые Богом всеми теми талантами и знаниями, коими обладаете Вы. Для нас ИТ - лишь увлечение, позволяющее отойти от повседневных проблем и забот. Спасибо за критику.